# WIll the iphone simulator run a naked command line?

Tags: ios-simulator

Does the iphone simulator require a bundle? I tried to run it on a plain executable and got

```
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain
   Code=1  UserInfo=0x1002336c0 "Unknown error."
```

using the open source iphonesim driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it the path of the bundle with the .app suffix that XCode generates. By default this is in the "build" subdirectory of an iphone project. Also, there is currently a bug in the project that requires you to use the absolute path.